# Register/Unregister COM dll verbs are not working in vista

Tags: shell, windows-vista, shell-verbs

I am trying to use the registry settings from [this](http://www.paulcilwa.com/Programming/03.Projects/Register_DLLs/index.asp) page to add two menu-items to the explorer context menu in vista to register and unregister COM DLLs. But for some reason they do not work. I have checked the registry using `Regedit` and the keys do exist on my system. I have also tried logging on and off the system several times but still no dice.

Has anyone ever faced this problem before? Were you able to resolve it? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

Which keys are you missing=? The ones you want to create, or the keys you want to register under?

Use [regmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896652.aspx) to monitor the registry access when you attempt to register your DLL.

The most likely cause thing is trying to register in a location that is no longer writable without elevation (you'll see an access denied on the respective key). Or maybe there's an error in the .reg file if you are using one, in that case you will see an attempt to write the wrong key, or no key at all.

Comment: I am not missing any keys, I was able to update the registry with the shell verb keys but I still cannot see the context menu items corresponding to register and unregister.